# How can I split one screen into two using Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, screen, raspberry-pi3, display, hdmi

I hav a Raspberry Pi and a display connected via HDMI. Now I'd like to split the screen, so I got a single line on top (like 2-3cm), to show some numbers and the screen beneth it maybe as one or also split. How does it work and can I run single "full screen" programs in the seperated sections afterwards?

Thanks and Greetings,
Elias

Comment: For non-programming questions, please use https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok I will, sorry

Comment: No worries. Not yet knowing that there's a better place to ask certain types of questions is nothing to apologize for.

Answer (score 1):

Look in to `tmux`, which will let you split the screen, running a shell in each. The splits can be resized, giving the effect you want.